# How to do random addition

Tags: python

I created a maths quiz as follow:

```
import random
score=0
ask="Y"
while ask=="Y":
    num1=random.randint(1,20)
    num2=random.randint(1,20)
    answer=int(input(str(num1)+"+"+str(num2)+":"))
    correctanswer=num1+num2
    if(correctanswer==answer):
        print("well done")
        score=score+10
    else:
        print("Oh no....")
    ask=input("Want another one? (Y/N)")
print("your score is: ", score)
```

The problem is it is not stopping after 3 wrong tries. What should I add to the program to do so.

Comment: Do you want the loop to stop after 3 wron tries or jus tone wrong try?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import random
score=0
ask="Y"
errors = 0
max_tries = 3
while ask == "Y":
    num1=random.randint(1,20)
    num2=random.randint(1,20)
    answer=int(input(str(num1)+"+"+str(num2)+":"))
    correctanswer=num1+num2
    if(correctanswer==answer):
        print("well done")
        score=score+10
    else:
        errors += 1
        print("Oh no....")
    if errors >= max_tries:
        break
    ask = input("Want another one? (Y/N)")
print("your score is: ", score)
```

Answer (score 3):

Add `wrong_tries_counter`, explenations are in comments.

Note that we check if reached limit only when failing, to spare redundant checks.

```
import random
score=0
ask="Y"
# Initialize counter with zero
wrong_tries_counter     = 0
WRONG_TRIES_LIMIT       = 3
while ask=="Y":
    num1=random.randint(1,20)
    num2=random.randint(1,20)
    answer=int(input(str(num1)+"+"+str(num2)+":"))
    correctanswer=num1+num2
    if(correctanswer==answer):
        print("well done")
        score=score+10
    else:
        print("Oh no....")
        # Update wrong tries, when faild
        wrong_tries_counter += 1
        # Break if reached wrong tries limit
        if WRONG_TRIES_LIMIT == wrong_tries_counter:
            break
    ask=input("Want another one? (Y/N)")
print("your score is: ", score)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add break at this part of your code:

```
import random
score=0
ask="Y"
wrongs=0
while ask=="Y":
    num1=random.randint(1,20)
    num2=random.randint(1,20)
    answer=int(input(str(num1)+"+"+str(num2)+":"))
    correctanswer=num1+num2
    if(correctanswer==answer):
        print("well done")
        score=score+10
    else:
        print("Oh no....")
        wrongs+=1
        if wrongs==3:
            break
    ask=input("Want another one? (Y/N)")
print("your score is: ", score)
```

Comment: I tried it but it will stop after only one wrong try

Comment: Ok, i changed the code, it should break after 3 wrong answers now